# How to set javadoc for com.google.android.gms.maps?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, intellij-idea, google-api

Problem with setup documentation under android/intelij(12) for android google maps_v2 any1 has an idea how to do it?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Do you have jar with javadoc?

Comment: Nope, actually I have google-play-services.jar from google-play-services_lib module where I can't find javadoc. The question is more about, IF google maps_v2 has a javadoc at all (?)

Comment: I haven't seen any, so I guess no. I can only suggest posting a "feature" request for that on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2).

Comment: I have posted feature-request as Maciek suggested and to be honest I switched to android studio that is/was most Up-to-date ide for this platform.